# Data reading and storing in c#, (Concept..no code)

Tags: c#

I want to translate my Matlab code (least squares plane fitting) into C#.
I have many problems in understanding c#.
Let me ask here.
Reading a text file and storing data in xyz format in matrix (e.g., xyzdata= xyz) in Matlab is quite easy.
Translating it into CSharp?
How can I read [x y z] without knowing length of file and how can I store it in Matrix form?
Thank you very much for your help and If someone has plane fitting code / link, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the content of your text file, but [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) is the easiest way to read a text file into a string array representing all lines in the file. No trouble with having to know the length of the file.

If the lines contain the entries of your matrix, the next step would be looping through the lines and for each line use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get the individual elements.

When you've got that far, you have all information for creating a matrix of the required size. To fill its elements you're going to need [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or Decimal.Parse to convert the elements as string into numbers.

However, hard to tell from your post what kind of matrix you'll need (probably a multi dimensional array). Search "[matrix] [c#]" here at stack overflow. And try "[math] [.net]" to find posts on math libraries for .net.